# How to filter objects by CharField

Tags: python, django, object, filter, django-views

I want to filter `cases_alert`(class) by `CaseAlert.alert_type` which is a `CharField`. But the parameter of the filter function is not `CharField`.

Can anyone help me to fix this?
Thank you.

models.py

```py
class CaseAlert(models.Model):
    alert_type = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

views.py

```py
cases_alerts = CaseAlert.objects.all().prefetch_related('reports').filter(
    CaseAlert.alert_type.in_(['u1'])).order_by(CaseAlert.alert_key)
```

Comment: You can just use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) so, `filter(alert_type__in=['u1'])`

Comment: It would be nice if you removed all elements that are not related to your question. In this case: `prefetch_related('reports)`. There is no such field in your model _in the question_, so this cannot possibly work and is confusing for readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
CaseAlert.objects.prefetch_related('reports').filter(
    alert_type__in=['u1']
).order_by('alert_key')
```

If the list contains only one element, you should not use the [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
CaseAlert.objects.prefetch_related('reports').filter(
    alert_type='u1'
).order_by('alert_key')
```